# docker-compose mongo rails connection fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker-compose

I have a rails application with mongodb, in development environment.
Unable to connect mongodb with docker. Can connect to local mongodb with same mongoid config. I tried changing host as localhost to 0.0.0.0 but did not work.
What is missing in the settings ?

My doubt is mongo in Docker hasn't started or binded. If i make changes in mongoid config to read: :nearest, it says no nodes found.

error message is,
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure in Product#index

Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #]>

Dockerfile

```
#FROM ruby:2.2.1-slim
FROM rails:4.2.1
MAINTAINER Sandesh Soni, <my@email.com>
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
RUN mkdir /gmv
WORKDIR /gmv
# Add db directory to /db
ADD Gemfile /gmv/Gemfile
RUN bundle install
ADD ./database /data/db
ADD . /gmv
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/gmv
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo
  command: "--smallfiles --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port 27027 -v"
  volumes:
    - data/mongodb:/data/db
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Where are you trying to connect to your MongoDB instance? If you want to connect to it in your browser, you need to point to your Docker host URL (`boot2docker ip`) giving it the correct port (`27027` in your case). If you want to conenct to it from the `web` container, you can either use the `db` hostname (it is automatically added by Docker in `/etc/hosts/`) or the env vars created by Docker Compose (something similar to `YOURAPP_DB_1_PORT_27027_TCP_ADDR` (see here https://docs.docker.com/compose/env/).

Comment: I am using linux machine, not a mac. I tried using MYAPP_DB_1_PORT_27027_TCP_ADDR, i get error 
Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:70197059955820 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.53.53:27017">]> 
i am using on local development, so 0.0.0.3000 is the url; The above resolved address 127.0.53.53 means clashing ip.

Answer (score 0):

On your host machine execute `docker run yourapp env`, then in output look for ip address related to your database. That ip address & port you need to use to connect to your database running in container.

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854468/docker-compose-to-run-django-with-mongodb)